# GoogleSheet If column contains value then return a list of time to multiple rows

Tags: list, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to build up an event schedule on Google Sheets.

The idea is to split Weekends and Weekdays; during the weekends, the event starts at 18:00, while on weekdays, it begins at 16:00.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sun | 18:00 |
|  | 18:30 |
|  | 19:00 |
|  | 19:30 |
| -------- | -------- |
| Mon | 16:00 |
|  | 16:30 |
|  | 17:00 |
|  | 17:30 |
|  | 18:00 |
|  | 18:30 |
|  | 19:00 |
|  | 19:30 |

I'd like to use a formula to illiterate the time slots or app scripts to pull the time slot.
If column A = Sat or Sun, Column B [18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30] but input to multiple rows.
Else Column B [16:00,16:30,17:00,17:30,18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30]

ADD ON with Complete Project:

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glYlh.png)

To clean up the script, now it's a bit hard to read as the way to write it is to add a formula behind it.

`

```
function updateEFformulas() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const row = 553;
  const rg = sh.getRange("$C$553:$N561");
  //Logger.log(sh.getRange(553,7).getValue())
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  Logger.log(rg.getValues()[row])
  const input_range = sh.getRange("$C$553:$N561").getValues();
  Logger.log(input_range[row])
  //Logger.log(vs)
  vs.forEach((a,b) => {
  sh.getRange(b+row,2).setValue('=if'+'(A'+(b+row)+'="","", text(WEEKDAY(A'+(b+row)+'),"ddd"))').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
  sh.getRange(b+row,3).setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontWeight("bold");
  sh.getRange(b+row,4).setValue('=C'+(b+row)+'+(0.25/24)').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontWeight("bold");
  sh.getRange(b+row,5).setValue('=C'+(b+row)+'+(2/24)').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
  sh.getRange(b+row,6).setValue('=D'+(b+row)+'+(2/24)').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");})
  input_range.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == "") {
    //=if(G2="","",IFERROR(index(importrange("other sheet","agency raw!d:d"),MATCH(G2,IMPORTRANGE("other sheet","agency raw!e:e"),0)),"Not found"))
      sh.getRange(i+row,7).setValue('=if'+'(H'+(i+row)+'="","",IFERROR(index(importrange("other sheet","agency raw!u:u"),MATCH'+'(H'+(i+row)+',IMPORTRANGE("other sheet","agency raw!e:e"),0)),"Not found"))').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
      sh.getRange(i+row,9).setValue('=if'+'(H'+(i+row)+'="","",IFERROR(index(importrange("other sheet","agency raw!d:d"),MATCH'+'(H'+(i+row)+',IMPORTRANGE("other sheet","agency raw!e:e"),0)),"Not found"))').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
      sh.getRange(i+row,10).setValue('=if'+'(H'+(i+row)+'="","",IFERROR(index(importrange("other sheet","agency raw!c:c"),MATCH'+'(H'+(i+row)+',IMPORTRANGE("other sheet","agency raw!e:e"),0)),"Not found"))').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
      //sh.getRange(i+row,10).setValue('=if'+'(G'+(i+row)+'<>"",G'+(i+row)+',"")').setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");
    }
  })
}


function Data_Vali(){
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//DEFINE MENU SHEET     
var sheetname = ['Oct Week3 of SignUp','Oct Week4 of SignUp','Nov Week1 of SignUp','Nov Week2 of SignUp'] 
sheetname.forEach(function(name) {
var menuSheet = sss.getSheetByName(name);  
var partSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Range"); // Range =['Y','N']
//Column J - status
var partCell = menuSheet.getRange('$L$553:$L561'); 
var partRange = partSheet.getRange('$A$2:$A$3');
var partRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(partRange).setAllowInvalid(false)
    .setHelpText("Wrong Entry").build();
partCell.setDataValidation(partRule).setFontWeight("bold");
```

`

One thing that is not working for me is:

The idea is to split Weekends and Weekdays. During the weekends, the event starts at 18:00, while on weekdays, it begins at 16:00.

I'd like to use a formula to illiterate the time slots or app scripts to pull the time slot. If column B = Sat or Sun, Column C [18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30] but input to multiple rows. Else Column C [16:00,16:30,17:00,17:30,18:00,18:30,19:00,19:30]

Answer (score 0):

```
function schedule() {
  const ds =[["ColumnA","ColumnB"],["Sun","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Mon","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Tue","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Wed","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Thu","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Fri","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"],["Sat","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"]];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,ds.length,ds[0].length).setValues(ds)
}

function scheduleCreator() {
  const sA = [[["Sun","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Mon","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Tue","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Wed","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Thu","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Fri","16:00"],["","16:30"],["","17:00"],["","17:30"],["","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"],["---","---"]],[["Sat","18:00"],["","18:30"],["","19:00"],["","19:30"]]];
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
 const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
 let d = 0;
 vs.forEach((e,i) => {
   if(e) {
     let dt = new Date(e);
     sh.insertRowsAfter(i + 2 + d,sA[dt.getDay()].length - 1);
     sh.getRange(i + 2 + d, 2, sA[dt.getDay()].length,sA[dt.getDay()][0].length).setValues(sA[dt.getDay()]);
     d += sA[dt.getDay()].length - 1;
   }
 }); 
}
```

Sheet0 Start:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 12/14/2022 |
| 3 | 12/15/2022 |
| 4 | 12/16/2022 |
| 5 | 12/17/2022 |
| 6 | 12/18/2022 |
| 7 | 12/19/2022 |
| 8 | 12/20/2022 |
| 9 | 12/21/2022 |
| 10 | 12/22/2022 |
| 11 | 12/23/2022 |
| 12 | 12/24/2022 |

Sheet0 with Schedule inserted:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 12/14/2022 | Wed | 16:00 |
| 3 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 4 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 5 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 6 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 7 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 8 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 9 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 10 |  | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12/15/2022 | Thu | 16:00 |
| 12 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 13 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 14 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 15 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 16 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 17 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 18 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 19 |  | --- | --- |
| 20 | 12/16/2022 | Fri | 16:00 |
| 21 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 22 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 23 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 24 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 25 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 26 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 27 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 28 |  | --- | --- |
| 29 | 12/17/2022 | Sat | 18:00 |
| 30 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 31 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 32 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 33 | 12/18/2022 | Sun | 18:00 |
| 34 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 35 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 36 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 37 |  | --- | --- |
| 38 | 12/19/2022 | Mon | 16:00 |
| 39 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 40 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 41 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 42 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 43 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 44 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 45 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 46 |  | --- | --- |
| 47 | 12/20/2022 | Tue | 16:00 |
| 48 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 49 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 50 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 51 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 52 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 53 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 54 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 55 |  | --- | --- |
| 56 | 12/21/2022 | Wed | 16:00 |
| 57 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 58 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 59 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 60 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 61 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 62 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 63 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 64 |  | --- | --- |
| 65 | 12/22/2022 | Thu | 16:00 |
| 66 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 67 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 68 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 69 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 70 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 71 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 72 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 73 |  | --- | --- |
| 74 | 12/23/2022 | Fri | 16:00 |
| 75 |  |  | 16:30 |
| 76 |  |  | 17:00 |
| 77 |  |  | 17:30 |
| 78 |  |  | 18:00 |
| 79 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 80 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 81 |  |  | 19:30 |
| 82 |  | --- | --- |
| 83 | 12/24/2022 | Sat | 18:00 |
| 84 |  |  | 18:30 |
| 85 |  |  | 19:00 |
| 86 |  |  | 19:30 |

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the quick turnaround. I've tried the code, and it works. However, since this is a sign-up sheet and the date differs based on the month. The weekday ( Sun/Mon/Tue etc., changes based on the date)

I've adjusted my questions and hope you can review them again and let me know if there is another way to redefine ds.